# Pass int from outer query into OPENQUERY used as subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to improve the performance of a very large and complex query.  Below is the relevant portions. I pass the id to the where clause and get back an orderid.  I need to get the order comments from another database on a linked server.  I understand that I have to pass the query string to OpenQuery, it cannot have dynamic values.  In my example I've hard coded it.

How do I get the S.OrderId value and pass it to the OpenQuery?  I've tried some of the example but none do this with a subquery.  Declare and Set throw errors inside of my main SELECT.

```
SELECT    S.ID AS Id
        , S.OrderID 
        , (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQL2014A, 'SELECT TOP 1  SECCOMMENT FROM TMWAMS.dbo.ORDERSEC WHERE ORDERID = 1515552')) AS COMMENTS
FROM ShopPO S WHERE ID = 230
```

Comment: *"How do I get the S.OrderId value and pass it to the OpenQuery?"* You can't. You'll need to use 4 part naming to reference the table (in the `FROM` as a `JOIN`), however, it will have significant performance impacts as the entire table will likely to passed from the remote instance to the local one, loaded into `tempdb` and then scanned.

Comment: That's the problem.  I have one linked reference that nearly doubles the time it takes the query to run. I don't need all that data to come over to the local server, just a single field.